# Need to implement share functionality in my android app,

Tags: android

I need to support my android app to share data between facebook, twitter and linkedin. what i  did was in my share tab item display and table with above site login page url. when use tap on the table row i'll load the site login page on web view.

what i want if user has already installed and appellation/s which support above social network sites i want to prompt the user with available application and ask him to choose from list or use the default as webview login.can some one help me to solve this issue.
sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android way to share content is to send an ACTION_SEND intent. Construct the Intent object with the correct mime type and data, then you can use the `Intent#createChooser` method to generate a wrapper Intent that will allow the user to choose the share target from a list. Any app the user has installed that can accept that type of content will be presented to the user.

With this approach apps are able to cooperate to share content without being directly aware of one another's existence.